# Only Two Applications ever running for Synapse Notebooks in For Each activity

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse

I am running a Synapse Notebook in a For Each activity in a Synapse Pipeline.  The notebook loads some data from the datalake into the database and some custom processing (which is why we're using a Notebook):

[image]

No matter what configuration of Spark pools I use: small, medium, large, auto-scale, not auto-scale, dynamic allocators, number of nodes 3 or 5 or 10, dynamic or fixed, there are only ever **two** Spark applications running:

[image: always two there are, no more, no less]

The For Each activity should run 10 executions of the notebook.  and is **not** capped at two, but set at the default.  So in theory I would expect this to execute all 10 notebook calls concurrently.  Is there any other Spark config which is causing this to cap at 2?

Comment: Any view on this @NiharikaMoola-MT or do you know good Synapse Spark people to talk to?

Comment: Could it be a quota limit? Like the pool won't run a job unless there are enough resources available? There is no visibility into that in the Workspace, so I don't know how you would check. IIRC, the default quota is very small.

Comment: Good thought but I don’t think so.  It allows us to to stand up many workers in the pool, they’re just not doing anything most of the time.

Comment: You couldn't have a look at this one for me please @UtkarshPal-MT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue, in each notebook setting we decreased the **max amount of executors** to a really low amount. You can see the # of executors being used after a run by using the Spark GUI. This helped us bench mark a reasonable number to lower our max executor number. In most cases a max executor of 2 is all that is needed.

Consider the math for a small pool (4vCores) with max nodes 40. If I set the max executors in my notebook= 2, then that notebook will consume 2 executors X 4vCores = 8 total cores. The total the pool has to offer is 40 max nodes X 4vCores = 160 cores. The notebook is using 5% of the pool.

But if you only allow your small pool 10 nodes and a max of 5 executors per notebook. The total available is 10X4= 40. The notebooks would each use 20 and that's how you can have only 2 notebooks running at a time.

Comment: Sounds promising, I will look into it.  Are you tweaking the settings using the config magic or some other method?  An example would be great!  Plus I need to check what the defaults are.

Comment: Tweaking via notebook settings gear on the top right of a notebook.

Comment: Yes, the max amount is unfortunately a limit, and Livy reserves excess capacity to allow for the max.  You should also look at decreasing the number of vcores per executor if you wan to get a higher density of notebooks running in your Synapse spark pool